# Why can't I print a hash table in a hash like format?

Tags: perl, hash, perl-data-structures

I have the following snippet in Perl:

```
my $a1 = [ qw(rock pop musical) ];  
my $b1 = [ qw( mystery action drama )];  
my $c1 = [ qw( biography novel periodical)];   

my %media = (  
    music => $a1,  
    file => $b1,  
    print => $c1   
);
```

I try to print it as follows:

```
use Data::Dumper;  
print Dumper (%media);
```

I got this:

```
$VAR1 = 'file';  
$VAR2 = [   
          'mystery',  
          'action',  
          'drama'  
        ];  
$VAR3 = 'music';  
$VAR4 = [  
          'rock',  
          'pop',  
          'musical'  
        ];  
$VAR5 = 'print';  
$VAR6 = [  
          'biography',  
          'novel',  
          'periodical'  
        ];
```

It prints the hash like a list. What I was expecting was something like this which denotes that it is a hash.

```
$VAR1 = {  
          'file' => [  
                      'mystery',  
                      'action',  
                      'drama'  
                    ],  
          'music' => [  
                       'rock',  
                       'pop',  
                       'musical'  
                     ],  
          'print' => [  
                       'biography',  
                       'novel',  
                       'periodical'  
                     ]  
        };
```

But I only get this if I convert the `%media` to an anonymous hash reference.
Why don't I get a hash-like print when I Dump the hash table?

Answer (score 5):

Dumper takes a list of *scalars* to dump. Pass references to hashes and arrays if you want to dump those.

```
print Dumper(\%media);
```

Comment: This is a form of work-arround though right? I mean how would I know from a print like in the OP if a hash is being used or a list?

Comment: @Cratylus if subroutine doesn't have prototype hash is always passed as list

Comment: Under normal circumstances lists are flattened.  A hash in list context returns a list of key=>value pairs, in no particular key order.  `print Dumper %hash` flattens the hash into a list.  `print Dumper \%hash` passes a hashref to Dumper, and you get a more traditional hash dump format.  I wouldn't call it a workaround -- it's simply how it's done.  List flattening is a feature.  Hash refs are a feature of the language as well.